# Getting a list of all DBpedia resources

Tags: java, sparql, dbpedia

I am looking for a list of dbpedia resources, that is a list of URIs like
    `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Roger_Federer, http://dbpedia.org/resource/Berlin`
Is there a way to write a SPARQL query or a dataset yielding this list?

Comment: That will be a very long list. I don't think there's a single file that contains only that, but you might explore the [downloads of the latest (2016-10) dataset](https://wiki.dbpedia.org/develop/datasets/dbpedia-version-2016-10). It's probably worth explaining *why* you want this list, as there may be better ways to achieve your actual goal.

Comment: download the dataset and load **all subjects and objects** of the RDF triples into a list. doing it in Java might need some more memory though, and even with stream based parsing this might take some time. don't forget to do a filter on non-literal objects indeed

Comment: and yes, it might be interesting to know the purpose of this list given that you already asked some questions before that are to some extent related, somebody here might give you hints on existing implementations that already do what you're trying to implement